# Converting geometry to geography using org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS?

Tags: java, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I'm trying to convert com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry to geography, using the GeoTools package - org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS. This is my code:

```
public Geometry getGeography() {
    Geometry geo = null;
    try {
        JTS.toGeographic(this.geo, CRS.decode("EPSG:" + Integer.toString(this.geo.getSRID()), true));
    } catch (TransformException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FactoryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return geo;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:0" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS".
```

Can anybody assist on why the this.geo.getSRID() return 0?

Answer (score 1):

JTS geometries in GeoTools don't make use of the SRID value, so it will always be 0 unless you make a special effort to set it to something.

You should query your FeatureType to find out the SRS for the layer.