# Geotools Transform to new coordinate system not working

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotools

I'm trying to convert from EPSG 26191 to WGS, here is the code im using to transform but it still prints for me when I get the SRID  as 26191.

```
    CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:26191");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS= CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(targetCRS, sourceCRS);
    var x = JTS.transform(sourceGeometry, transform);
    System.out.println(x.getSRID());
```

Comment: do the actual coordinates change? GeoTools (and JTS) don't actually do anything with the SRID stored in the geometry

Comment: related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97265/converting-geometry-to-geography-using-org-geotools-geometry-jts-jts

Comment: oh yes! you're right thank you SRID doesn't change  but my geometry coordinates changed !

Comment: But there is still a problem my polygon is not where it supposed to be i don't know why

Comment: please add an example input and the expected and observed output

Comment: i fixed it i noticed that the conversion swapped long with lat and i added to sourceCRS the true argument

Answer (score 1):

After debugging I noticed that the geometry is changed but the SRID is not.  As @lan Turton told me,
you can update it yourself if you want.
One thing I noticed is that the long lat is inversed and for that you just need to add the attribute true to CRS.decode method.

```
sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:26195", true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
return JTS.transform(sourceGeometry, transform);
```

Comment: that's expected behaviour - see https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html for more discussion